# C++ static null pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, static

I can't figure out the following situation:
I've 3 classes:

AA.h

```
class AA
{
   public:
   AA();
   static CC *i;
};
```

BB.h

```
class BB
{
  public:
  BB();
  void static setI(CC *i);
};
```

CC.h

```
class CC
{
  public:
  CC();
};
```

AA.cpp

```
AA::AA(){}
CC *AA::i= nullptr;
```

BB.cpp

```
BB::BB(){}

void BB::setI(CC *i)
{
  i = new CC();
  cout<<i<<endl;
  cout<<AA::i;
}
```

CC.cpp

```
CC::CC(){}
```

So I've a static pointe of type CC in the class A.
And i start the main in the following way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BB::setI(AA::i);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
//0xaeed70
//0
```

So why `AA::i` does not equal `i`?

Comment: Are you familiar with scope and name hiding? That pointers are passed by value like all non reference types?

Comment: Assigning to a parameter has no effect on any variable whose value you passed as that parameter. It's the same as if you passed an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter type of `BB::setI` is `CC *i`, the pointer itself is passed by value, `i` is copied from the argument. Any modification on `i` inside the function has nothing to do with the original argument `AA::i`.

What you want might be pass-by-reference, i.e.

```
void BB::setI(CC *&i)
{
  i = new CC();
  cout<<i<<endl;
  cout<<AA::i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `i = new CC()` variable `i` is local variable of function `BB::setI` which was initialized with the value of `AA::i` because you called function like `BB::setI(AA::i);`. Assigning any value to `i` will only change the value of this local variable, not the value of some other variable that has been used to initialize it when you called the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same situation as this smaller example:

```
int i = 0;

void setI(int x)
{
    x = 1234;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << i;
}

int main()
{
    setI(i);
}
```

As you can see more clearly here, you're assigning a new value to the function's parameter.
This parameter is unrelated to `AA`'s member.

Regardless of its type, if you want a function to modify an object, you need to pass it a reference (or pointer) to that object; you can't pass the object's value.